# Aligning 2 lines of text on the right with Icon of same height on the left

Tags: css

I want possibly the simplest CSS code for aligning 2 lines of text with 1 single icon on the left side. I am attaching the sample here: https://prnt.sc/1udg41j
Please help with the minimal code if possible.

Comment: Please include code here, don't link images https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image is within the same parent as the text and then to have the icon be on the left side. I believe you'll need to type:

```
example {
 float: left;
}
```

It would be much easier if you included the code. :P

Comment: I want to get a similar style, do not want to copy that code. That website is using lots of coding for that, I don't think it will need that much. I just want to see ICON on the left side and 2 like of text on the right side but with an equal height.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.iconbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 42px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="iconbox">
    <span class="icon">&#8512;</span>
    <div class="detail">
      <h3>heading here</h3>
      <p>discription here..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="iconbox">
    <span class="icon">&#8512;</span>
    <div class="detail">
      <h3>heading here</h3>
      <p>discription here..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="iconbox">
    <span class="icon">&#8512;</span>
    <div class="detail">
      <h3>heading here</h3>
      <p>discription here..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```